# imshow() not showing changed pixel values

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I converted a RGB iamge to gray and then to binary. I wanted that the white pixels of binary image be replaced by pixel value of gray image. Though the command window shows that all 1s are replaced with gray pixel value but same is not reflected in the image. 
The binary image (bw) and the new image (newbw) looks exactly. Why so ?

```
clc;clear all;close all;
i = imread('C:\Users\asus\Documents\Academics 2014 (SEM 7)\DIP\matlabTask\im1.jpg');
igray = rgb2gray(i);
bw = im2bw(igray);
[m,n]=size(bw);
newbw = zeros(m,n);
for i=1:m
 for j=1:n

    if bw(i,j)==1         
        newbw(i,j)=igray(i,j);  

    else
        newbw(i,j)=bw(i,j); 
    end
 end
end

subplot(311),imshow(igray),subplot(312),imshow(bw),subplot(313),imshow(newbw)
```

Comment: If you do just `figure,imshow(newbw)`, is it giving you the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why is because when you are creating your new blank image, this is automatically created as `double` type.  When doing `imshow`, if you provide a `double` type image, the dynamic range of the pixel intensities are expected to be between `[0,1]` where `0` is black and `1` is white.  Anything less than 0 (negative) will be shown as black, and anything greater than 1 will be shown as white.

Because this is surely not the case in your image, and **a lot** of the values are going to be `> 1`, you will get an output of either black or white.  I suspect your image is of type `uint8`, and so the dynamic range is between `[0,255]`.

As such, what you need to do is `cast` your output image so that it is of the same type as your input image.  Once you do this, you should be able to see the gray values displayed properly.  All you have to do now is simply change your `newbw` statement so that the variable is of the same class as the input image.  In other words:

```
newbw = zeros(m,n,class(igray));
```

Your code should now work.  FWIW, you're not the first one to encounter this problem.  Almost all of my questions that I answer when using `imshow` are due to the fact that people forget that putting in an image of type `double` and type `uint*` behave differently.

---

## Minor note

For efficiency purposes, I personally would not use a `for` loop.  You can achieve the above behaviour by using indexing with your `boolean` array.  As such, I would replace your `for` loop with this statement:

```
newbw(bw) = igray(bw);
```

Whichever locations in `bw` are true or logical 1, you copy those locations from `igray` over to `newbw`.

Comment: Nice one @ rayryeng! I was just about to comment on the data type being probably incorrect. Oh and I would also add for the OP that naming a variable/image 'i' is subject to creating unwanted behaviour...so avoid this as much as possible. +1 !

Comment: @Dima - Wow.  Surprised I didn't catch that small spelling typo.  I'm usually on the ball when catching those errors.  Thanks I guess!

Comment: @rayryeng, well, you did make it bold. :) So I noticed.:)

Comment: @Dima - hahaha thank you :)  alot is actually one of my pet peeves when I spell something.  I'm surprised I didn't catch that one.  I was in a rush to post an answer, so when I looked at the post the first time, I didn't notice any spelling errors... but then again, I was in a rush.  Thank you for correcting :)

Comment: @Benoit_11 - Sorry, I thought I replied to you.  Thanks for your comments, and I agree about `i` as a variable too :)

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up!
One more: If I happen to replace logical 0 levels in the binary image by gray levels and keep logical 1 as it is then the output is unexpected. 
Though 0s are replaced by original pixel value and 1s remain as it is but imshow() shows the white portion of image as black too. (but black portion are rightly shown as gray )

Comment: @Rishi - If you want to do this, you need to do `newbw(i,j)=uint8(255*double(bw(i,j)));` because `bw(i,j)` is 1 and you want this to map to white, which is `255` in `uint8`.  I'm assuming that you changed the `if` statement so that it's checking for `0` instead of `1`?  BTW, you can do this without a `for` loop.... just saying.